# ASP.NET CORE Razor, how configure Json.Encode to ignore circular references?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using C# `Json.Encode` to add some data into our DOM.

```
<div data-model='@Json.Encode(cliente)'>
```

However there is some circular reference into our model.

Is possible to configure the global converter to ignore those circular references?

Comment: Not sure but I think you can decorate your properties of the model to prevent serialization, and hence, circular references: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute to the property that would start the circular reference. For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

So, assuming you have an instance of `foo`, the JSON serializer will delve into the `Bar` reference, but will not continue into the `Foo` reference, there, because it's ignored.

You can only do this one way, though. If you start with an instance of `Bar`, you won't get the `Foo` reference at all, because again, it's simply ignored. If you need to handle various different scenarios like this, you'll need to utilize separate classes (call them view models, DTOs, whatever), where you simply set it up so that the circular reference doesn't exist in the first place. This is not a bad idea to just do, *in general*. In other words, you can use custom built classes instead of `[ScriptIgnore]` in the first place.

Comment: adding script ignore was not enough, It must be added `scriptignore` with `override`

Comment: Only if indeed you are overriding the property, i.e. the property was already defined without that attribute in a base class.

Comment: just clarifying. I must add `[ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]` to the attribute. I do not created any other class overriding it. However i do suspect that ASP.NET creates a Dynamic Type that overrides my class.

Comment: If the property is virtual and you're using the entity directly, then, yes. EF created a proxy class that derived from the entity to override the property.